# Spring: Method Not Allowed on file uploading

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, http-status-code-405

I'm writing REST controller which should allow users to upload their files.

I have a class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/profiles/{userId}/files")
public class FileController {

   @PostMapping(path = "upload")
   public String uploadFile(@PathVariable("userId") long userId,
                                             @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
   //some logic here

   }
```

But I get

```
{
"timestamp": 1502301243676,
"status": 405,
"error": "Method Not Allowed",
"message": "Method Not Allowed",
"path": "/profiles/12351/files/upload"
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Post request without @PathVariable works fine, but I need this one.

Comment: How are you invoking this Resource?

Comment: @RossiRobinsion via Postman

Comment: Probably need `CSRF` Token.

Comment: @RossiRobinsion it doesn't look like this. I don't have any security at the moment.

Comment: Can you show us the `POSTMAN` request and with headers if any?

Comment: This is why you use jaxrs, shorter annotations faster development.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, guys. At least I found the reason.
It was my fault: I have many different controllers and one of them was 
`"/profiles/{userId}/{source}"` with the GET method which was mapped on the same endpoint.
So this controller tried to handle my request, but couldn't.
I changed path to it it and my first one became work.
Thank you for your attentions and answers.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code

```
@RestController
    @RequestMapping("/profiles/{userId}/files")
    public class FileController {

       @RequestMapping(value = "upload", method = RequestMethod.POST )
       public String uploadFile(@PathVariable("userId") long userId,
                                                 @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
       //some logic here

       }
```

Comment: @PostMapping doesn't have the "method" parameters. It's equivalent to the @RequestMapping(method = POST)

Comment: @Akash  requestmapping with requestmethod post is equivalent to postmapping, your code is the same

Comment: @AmerQarabsa requestmapping contains method , as per spring document, https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html please have a  look ,  i dont know why you down voted my answer.

Comment: @Akash yes requestmapping + requestMethod.post = postmapping , there is not real difference between the question and your answer